# Signature of a tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, tridiagonal-matrices

Let $A$ be a tridiagonal matrix of the form
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & 1 \\
1 & a_2 & 1 \\
& 1 & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
& & & 1 & a_n
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the diagonal elements $a_i$ are integers. Since $A$ is symmetric, it has $n$ real eigenvalues (up to algebraic multiplicity) $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$. We define the **signature** of $A$ as the number of positive eigenvalues minus the number of negative eigenvalues. In this particular case, does there exist a simpler expression for the signature of $A$ in terms of the integers $a_i$? I know [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) can be used if we manage to find the appropriate similarity transformation, but I'm not sure what kind of similarity transformation would make matters simpler in this case.